# How to get backend instance from python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am currently using python-social-auth and added a backend `MyOAuth` which `BaseOAuth1`, inside the `BaseOAuth1` class there is a handy `oauth_request` instance method which I would like to make use of outside of the class.

https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/backends/oauth.py

I tried instantiate the class directly but looks like I am missing some context.

Is there a way reference that `MyOAuth` backend instance? I am expecting something like

`request.user.social_auth.get(provider='MyOAuth').backend.oauth_request(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sweet, posted on the github project and got an answer.

https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/114

For now:

```
from social.apps.django_app.utils import load_strategy

strategy = load_strategy(backend='MyOAuth')
social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='MyOAuth')
backend = backend(strategy=strategy)
backend = social.get_backend(strategy)
backend.oauth_request(...)
```

The author will release a helper to do this easily.

```
social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='MyOAuth')
backend = social.get_backend_instance()
```